# Indy C++ builder, SNMP get?

Tags: c++builder, snmp, indy

I've just started learning to write application use Indy to send SNMP get query but don't know how to? 
I don't ask for code but suggestions so I can write my own. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the Indy SNMP component? (TIdSNMP)

Comment: Also, say which version of C++Builder you are using whenever you post about it

Answer (score 1):

Indy has a `TIsSNMP` component.  Set `TIdSNMP.Community` and such as needed, then call `TIdSNMP.Query.MIBAdd()` to specify the OID(s) you are interested in, then call `TIdSNMP.SendQuery()`, then use `TIdSNMP.Reply.MIBGet()` to retrieve the OID value(s) as needed.  Or use `TIdSNMP.QuickSend()` if there is only 1 OID you are interested in.